# Stieltjes differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I have the following differential equation that I want to solve:
$$ dy(t) = -d[\alpha(t)\cdot  t]\,\,\,\,,y(0) = 50$$ where $[\cdot]$ is the greatest integer function.

My guess is that $$y(t) = 50 -\int _0^t d[\alpha(s)\cdot s] = 50 - [\alpha(s)\cdot s]$$ but I can't justify it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be a real-valued function of bounded variation, then so is $A_t:=\alpha(t)\cdot t$. Thus $A$ defines a Stiltjes-measure. Solving a Stieltjes differential equation $$\frac{dy(t)}{dA_t}=f(t,y(t))$$ for $y$ means finding a stiljes measure $y$ (or the corresponding function of bounded variation) such that the Radon-Nikodym derivative eqauls $f(t,y(t))$ (this can be found in chapter 19 of [this Book](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/bookseries/03040208/206/supp/C)).

By the definition of the Radon-Nikodym derivative the following is valid:$$y(t)=y_0+\int_0^t dy(s)=y_0+\int_0^t \frac{dy(s)}{dA_s}dA_s=y_0+\int_0^t f(s,y(s))dA_s.$$ In your case you have  $f(t,y)=1$.